# c# programmatically rebuild windows index

Tags: c#, indexing

I was wondering if anyone would know how to go about rebuilding the windows index cache?

I'm not entirely sure if there's any API to control the windows index and wanted to know if anyone had any experience in this area.

Thank you all.

Comment: What is exactly Windows index ? Do you refer to Windows search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search), if so please update question

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266414(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Paul I believe that is what I was looking for, thank you sir.